# Rails 4.2 enum not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to use rails enum fields for the user status functionality in my app however enums don't seem to be working(I have used Devise to manage the user login, registration .etc).
this is the result in my rails console where the status appears as `status:0` instead of `status:pending` `status:active` `status:suspended`.etc

```
  user = User.first   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "email@gmail.com", encrypted_password:
 "$2a$11$TFSX2XkearxEz1JlRtd6hOcvj3ScqykNKEKrkqGYLDx...",
 reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil,
 remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at:
 "2016-06-10 22:57:03", last_sign_in_at: "2016-06-10 22:57:03",
 current_sign_in_ip: "::1", last_sign_in_ip: "::1", created_at:
 "2016-06-10 22:57:03", updated_at: "2016-06-11 10:59:41", first_name:
 "John", last_name: "Smith", phone: nil, **status: 0**>
```

but I have declared the status enum in my **user.rb**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  enum status: [:pending, :active, :suspended]
end
```

and here is my migration

```
class AddStatusColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change    
    add_column :users, :status, :integer, default: 0    
  end
end
```

Furthermore, when I use `user.pending?` (default) I get an error "undefined method `pending?'" for instance

```
    irb(main):014:0> user.pending?
NoMethodError: undefined method `pending?' for #<User:0x315dba8>
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):14
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

how do I fix this issue with rails enum?
Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the reply. it returns 0

Comment: Did you restart the Rails console after you added the `enum` declaration to your `User` model?

Comment: Yes that fixed it ... Thank you sooo much!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload or restart the Rails console when you change code in the application.

Depending on the type of change the faster reload might solve your problem:

```
> reload!
```

On bigger changes: When you added or removed gems or change code outside of the `app` folder (for example a initializer or something in the `lib` folder) you will need to exit and restart the console completely:

```
> exit
$ rails console
```